# Class variable that is an instance of itself

Tags: python, class, variables

Is something like this possible?

```
class Foo:
    BAR = Foo("bar")
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Currently this yields `NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined`.

Answer (score 6):

No. `annotations` only applies to variable and function annotations. Until the `class` statement as been completely executed, there is no class `Foo` to instantiate. You *must* wait until after `Foo` is defined to create an instance of it.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

Foo.BAR = Foo("bar")
```

---

You can always initialize `BAR = None`, then change the value of the attribute after the class is defined.

```
class Foo:
    BAR = None  # To be a Foo instance once Foo is defined
    ...

Foo.BAR = Foo("bar")  # Fulfilling our earlier promise
```

That might be desirable for documentation purposes, to make it clearer in the definition that `Foo.BAR` *will* exist, though with a different value. I can't think of a situation where that would be *necessary*, though.

Comment: One reason for doing the latter (although actually it is better to do `BAR: Foo`) is that `mypy` will complain: `error: "type[Foo]" has no attribute "BAR"`

Comment: `Bar: ClassVar['Foo']`, actually, since `Bar` is a class attribute, not an instance attribute. (And you can use `Foo` instead of `'Foo'` if you use `from __future__ import annotations`.)